# Connection time out eth0 and ufw

Tags: ssh

I have 4 VPS servers which I `ssh` into. One of them suddenly stopped and am not able to login. This is surely a firewall issue as I have done some `ufw` changes in it.

Tried to restart `eth0`, but it stopped in between. (`sudo ifdown eth0`)

*Can I make changes to this server from any other server?*

Comment: Either the server is yours and can pĥysically connect to it, or your hosting provider has some "remote console" mechanism to connect to it without any network.

Comment: @ponsfrilus Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1056137/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**